# Atom code editor - insert html comment

Tags: atom-editor

I'm aware of the shortcut (Mac) CMD+/ to comment out (HTML style) a line. Is there a shortcut or a way of doing the following. When I press a keybinding, the comment tags are inserted where the cursor is and the cursor gets moved inside the tags to write a comment (x):

```
<!-- x -->
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try inserting two hyphens and pressing *TAB*. It should expand to a full comment block with the cursor inside. It is a snippet.

Comment: That's it. Thank you.

Comment: Where can I find more examples of such snippets?

Answer (score 0):

Select the code you want to comment out and press Ctrl (or Command) + /